# middle school olympiad combinatorics has me stuck

Tags: combinatorics

Michael has 2 spider-man toys,2 iron-man toys, 2 Thor toys and 2 Hulk toys. The toys representing the same characters are identical. In how many ways can he place his toys in a row so the number of toys between two toys of the same kind is different for every kind of toy?

Comment: Wow, this does seem pretty complicated.  The way I am thinking about approaching this is by first arranging four different toys in a row.  For example, (S I T H) or (H S I T).  There are $4!$ ways to do this.  After that, you have to count the number of ways to place the remaining toys between the ones we've already placed, and that is where I am stumped.  Just throwing ideas out there.

Comment: Ok, but you could also have them all sandwiched together like $STIHHITS$

Comment: Sure; my method doesn't preclude that possibility.

Comment: Everyone is picking their examples very carefully.

Comment: This question has too many **SHIT**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK here goes... after a bit of thought (not sure it was worth it) I have a manageable set of cases.

The "separations" between the pairs must be four different numbers from $0$ to $6$, having an even sum from $6$ to $12$.  It is not too hard to enumerate all possibilities: we find that with one exception they all include $0,1$ or $2,3$ or $4,5$.  The exception is $6,4,2,0$.

Case $0,1$: we need a row including components AA and BCB.  Assume that AA comes before BCB.  In the following, - denotes one unknown letter while o denotes zero or more unknown letters.

- If BCB is at the end then we have ---AABCB or ----DBCB.  It is not hard to see that the first is impossible and the second can be completed in $3$ ways.
- If BCB is not at the beginning or end we have oAABCBDo or oAAoDBCBDo.  The first can be completed in $3$ ways, the second also in $3$.  Total so far, $9$ ways.

Case $2,3$: we need a row including components A--A and B---B.  It is not hard to see that one of the As must occur between the Bs, the other before or after: assume it is before.

- The pattern oACBA--Bo can be completed in $2$ ways, but one includes gaps of $0,1$ and has already been counted above.
- The pattern oABCA-Bo can be completed in $2$ ways.  Total so far, $12$ ways.

Case $4,5$: we must have A----A and B-----B, with a B occurring at the beginning or end: assume it is at the end.  Then we have AB---ACB; it can be completed in $3$ ways, but one includes $0,1$ and has already been counted.

Total so far $14$ ways.  But because of the symmetry assumptions I have made, each of these could be done in reverse: total, $28$ ways.  It is easy to see that the pattern $6,4,2,0$ can be realised in only one way: total, $29$ ways.  And finally, the letters S,I,T,H can replace A,B,C,D in $4!$ ways.  Final answer, $29\times4!$.

**Addendum**.  In answer to a comment, the sum of the "separations" must be even because if the locations are $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ etc then we can write down the sum and simplify it modulo $2$ to get
$$\eqalign{|a_1-a_2|-1+|b_1-b_2|-1+\cdots
  &\equiv a_1-a_2-1+b_1-b_2-1+\cdots\cr
  &\equiv a_1+a_2+b_1+b_2+\cdots\cr
  &=1+2+\cdots+8\cr
  &=36\cr
  &\equiv 0\ .\cr}$$

Comment: why must the sum be even?

Comment: See addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A sequence output by a program pointed me to [A060963](http://oeis.org/A060963)

And the required answer is $29\cdot 4! = 696$

Not many references in that, must be a hard problem then!

Comment: I have a case-by-case solution which confirms this answer but even I think it's long and boring.  If anyone actually wants to see it please let me know.

Comment: Yeah, many cases involved, which is a job for computers, nothing much to think with this problem (or at least I could not). I guess it's a bad problem for olympiad!

Comment: The $4!$ can probably be explained with my comment, and the $29$ with the many cases you can have from there.  I can't believe this showed up on a *middle school* math olympiad.

Comment: I would really love to see your case by case study @david . Mabye the key was to make good cases or something. Anyways, I'm still hoping there may be some magical solution, but otherwise I must say I'm a little dissapointed in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First consider the problem with just $S,I,T$.   What are those distances between same letters?  They can be $0+2+4$, i.e.  $SITTIS$, or $1+2+3$, i.e. $SITSTI$.

For four pieces, we want distinct nonnegative partitions adding up to at most $12$:
0+2+4+6: $HSITTISH$
1+2+3+6: $HSITSTIH$
0+3+4+5: $SITHHSTI$
1+2+4+5: $SIHTHSTI$

These four partitions are the only ones possible with sum $12$.  The biggest part can't be greater than 6.  If the biggest part is 6, then the next biggest must be $\le 4$.  The biggest part can't be $4$, since $1+2+3+4<12$.

What remains is counting how many arrangements are possible for each case.  Certainly you can permute the letters ($4!$ ways for each).  Three of them may be reversed to give a different order, and there may be other representatives not listed for the permutations.  What is needed is a careful case analysis that my five-minute sketch does not have.

As David points out in the comments, the sum may be less than $12$.  It does have to be even though.
6=0+1+2+3: $HHSITSTI$
8=0+1+2+5: $SITSTHHI$
8=0+1+3+4: unknown

various others, there seem to be many cases.

Comment: What about $SITSTIHH$ giving partitions $0+1+2+3$ with sum $6$?

Comment: good point, will modify

Comment: Here's one for 0+1+3+4 = IHTHISST. For 0+1+4+5 = IHTHSSIT.

Comment: For 0+2+3+5 = IHSSTHIT.

Comment: All the ones with a 0 can be found by simply shifting around the pair with a zero distance.

Comment: Would it be better if we instead found those cases in which the number of toys in between is same for at least 2?